# Question about Narakas

Tags: karma

I want to ask the following: Is there a mention in the suttas or anywhere else that tells that there is a corresponding hell (Naraka) according to specific evil deeds? I wonder if it is a random thing or there is some corresponding hell to our evil deeds.

Answer (score 1):

Hells must corresponding to their evil deeds. **But there are uncountable various kamma leting their uncountable corresponding resultants arise in the same seconds, too.** Kamma just waiting the proper chance to let their resultants arise.

Most of hell appear in suttanta, but it will be easier to explain the hell by abhidhamma's rule.

In abhidhamma, there are trillion mind moments in a piece of second. Each mind moment must managing, kamma, their mind and mind factors, but only javana-duty mind moments have own resultants, vipaka.  **So, we done kamma over many thousands millions times each second.**

And each kamma will multiply it's resultants, vipaka, such as just 1 killing mind moment of last life can let uncountable resultant mind moments arise through next life, if that killing mind moment can win to process rebirth-duty, 1st mind moment of each rebirth, of next life.

Another, many kamma can work together by switch their resultants' arising between each other, such as killing mind  moment let its resultants through niraya-man's life, then the other kamma let it's resultants arise 
 by make niraya man very hurt his tongue.

Their are uncountable co-working in each second for one's life, such as a second of buddha's life on parinibbana's bed:

- Wholesome kamma let budhha's bhavanga mind moment arise.
- Each different wholesome kamma let buddha's each organ of 32 organs
  look the best beautiful.
- Unwholesome kamma let buddha's body sick.
- The other wholesome kamma let buddha watch many ariya around the 
  parinibbana's bed.

**These all happened only in a second, by a very various kamma. And this is just the example. In the full situation of this second, there are many various kamma giving their resultants.**

Answer (score 0):

> [MN130](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/mn/mn.130.than_en.html)
>
> "Then the hell-wardens, seizing (such a being) by the arms, present him to King Yama: 'This is a man, your majesty, with no respect for mother, no respect for father, no reverence for samanas, no reverence for brahmans, no honor for the leaders of his clan. Let your majesty decree his punishment.'...
>
> > "The Commentary notes that not everyone who falls into hell is tortured with all of these punishments: some of the tortures are skipped; in some cases the hell-being's kamma is exhausted before the full round of tortures is completed, so that he dies and is reborn elsewhere; and not everyone goes for repeated rounds. Also, we should note that punishment in hell is not for an eternity. As the discourse implies, when the hell-being's bad kamma is exhausted, he dies and is reborn elsewhere, in accordance with his remaining kamma."

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*

Answer (score -2):

'Hell' is 'suffering', 'pain', 'unhappiness', 'torment' &/or 'torture'. 'Hell' is described as undesirable unpleasant feelings, as follows:

> Bhikkhus, it is a gain for you, it is well gained by you, that you have obtained the opportunity for living the holy life. I have seen, bhikkhus, the hell named ‘Contact’s Sixfold Base.’ There whatever form one sees with the eye is undesirable, never desirable; unlovely, never lovely; disagreeable, never agreeable. Whatever sound one hears with the ear … Whatever odour one smells with the nose … Whatever taste one savours with the tongue … Whatever tactile object one feels with the body … Whatever mental phenomenon one cognizes with the mind is undesirable, never desirable; unlovely, never lovely; disagreeable, never agreeable.
>
> [SN 35.135](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn35.135)

The Pali suttas do not ascribe specific hells for specific unskilfull, heedless &/or evil deeds. For example, the [Cula Kammavibhanga Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn135) lists many types of unskilful actions & each action has the same potential general result of the 'unhappiness' of 'hell'.

However, if we use our common sense, we can discern in life that, in general (but not always), certain actions bring greater hellish results than another actions. For example, murder brings a longer prison sentence in hell than rape or corporate dishonesty; or the post-traumatic-hell of soldiers who fight in war is a greater hell than the hell of stealing or sexual misconduct. Or the hell of drug addiction is a strong hell.